# Python interactive CLI application?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm not even sure what these would be called? I used to write them in ADA running on VAX-VMS!

I want to make a simple menu-driven application that would let me display menus and use the cursor keys to navigate around them, choose items and navigate around the app. All fully old school text based.

I want to be able to take over the whole terminal window and display stuff in different places.

Is this possible in Python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check out the Python HOWTO on [Curses Programming with Python](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html) and here is the [library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html).

Comment: @MalphasWats happy to have been able to help.

Answer (score 10):

Another easy to use library is `Urwid` - Console User Interface Library.

http://excess.org/urwid/

http://excess.org/urwid/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at the different `curses` implementations.