# Wrapping an interactive CLI in python

Tags: python, popen

I am trying to wrap [gnugo](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnugo/) in a python script.

I've gone over the other questions in SO about wrapping CLI applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567371/wrapping-an-interactive-command-line-application-in-a-python-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873157/python-interactive-cli-application) and though they've helped somewhat, I haven't been able to get my script to work completely.  It appears the process is killed after the first input from stdin.

The script looks like this:

```
import subprocess 

proc = subprocess.Popen(['gnugo', '--mode', 'gtp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

c = raw_input('first command: ')

while True:
    r = proc.communicate(c)
    print 'gnugo says: ' + str(r)
    c = raw_input('next command: ')
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
$ python testgnu.py
first command: play b c4
gnugo says: ('= \n\n', None)
next command: genmove w
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testgnu.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = proc.communicate(c)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 754, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1307, in _communicate
    self.stdin.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I am running python 2.7.3 (and it probably doesn't matter but the gnugo version is 3.8).

Some answers in the other questions suggested [pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/) but I'd like to use as few external libraries as possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that [`Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) closes the file after performing its reads and writes.

You will have to manually call `proc.stdin.write(...)` to send the process text and `proc.stdout.read*()` to read text:

```
while True:
    proc.stdin.write(c)
    r = proc.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's it.  Now stdout.read() hangs, though that appears to be another issue.  Thanks!

Comment: `stdout.read()` will hang because `.read()` tries to read *all* the output. Instead, use `.readline()` (as in my example), which will only read one line at a time, or `.read(n)`, which will read (up to)  `n` bytes.

Comment: It appears the issue is that it never receives the EOF so it never terminates.  `gnugo` returns almost instantly when a player is playing a move.  I tried to explicitly write `\n` to stdin and it looks like that let `readline()` go through at least once (it hangs if I don't write `\n` to stdin), but `read()` still hangs.

Comment: Why are you calling straight `.read()`? You should only need to call `.readline()`… No?

Comment: `readline()` hangs as well.  I could pass stdin a bunch of newlines and just `readline()` them up.  At the moment, I don't quite understand why adding the newlines to the END of the stdin buffer makes `readline()` work multiple times (each time I get more of the data I want from stdout - not just the empty newlines you might expect).  I wouldn't mind doing `readline()` so long as it doesn't hang eventually.

Comment: I've got it now (and I think you were saying it all along).  The kick was that [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) strips newlines so they need to be added back if it's an interactive prompt I'm dealing with.  Your note about `read()` makes sense now.  (basically that it will always hang since its effectively just following the output of gnugo while gnugo is waiting for input)  Thanks again for the help!